# NServiceBus message types and thought process

Tags: nservicebus

In our scenario I'm thinking of using the pub sub technique. However I don't know which is the better option.

1 ########

A web service of ours will publish a message that something has happened when it is called externally, ExternalPersonCreatedMessage!

This message will contain a field that represents the destinations to process the message into (multiple allowed).

Various subscribers will subscribe. These subscribers will filter the message to see if any action is required by checking the destination field.

2 ########

A web service of ours will parse the incoming call and publish specific types of messages depending on the destinations supplied in the field. i.e. many Destination[*n*]PersonCreatedMessage messages would be created.

Subscribers will subscribe to only the specific message they care for. i.e. not having to filter any messages

QUESTIONS

Which of the above is the better option and why? And how do I stop myself from making RequestMessages. From what I've read/seen I should be trying to structure this in a way of PersonCreated, PersonDeleted i.e. SOMETHING HAS HAPPENED and **NOT** in the REQUEST SOMETHING TO HAPPEN form such as CreatePerson or DeletePerson

Are my thoughts correct? I've been looking for guidance on how to structure messages and making sure I don't go down a wrong path but have found no guidance out there on do's and dont's. Can any one help and guide? I want to try and get this correct from the off :)

Comment: Can you give some more detail as to what the business rules are?  It may be the case that you don't require Publishing.  In my experience content filtering is not a good way to go.

Comment: Adam. I feel like I'm going round in circles, but the [following](http://www.make-awesome.com/2011/11/robust-3rd-party-integrations-with-nservicebus/) helps explain the business scenario. The author very kindly (and much appreciated) helped me along the path to getting to grips with NServiceBus. This question mixed with the comment on the above blog are huge holes I still need to answer, and quickly. I don't know if these questions/issues are in any way indicating that NServiceBus is the wrong tool. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could use PServiceBus(pservicebus.codeplex.com) which allows you to publish a notification and have the subscriber subscribe using filters specifying that they want to receive the message only if it contain the specific field such as destination. The filtering would be done at the ESB server level rather than at the subscriber level, so the subscriber will not need to check whether the message fit their criteria or not. Using this approach would save you have to worry about publishing two different messages or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the integration scenario in the referenced article, it appears to me that you may need a Saga to complete the workflow of accept message -> operate on message -> send confirmation.  In the case that the confirmation is sent immediately after the operation, you could use NSBs message handler pipeline feature which allows you to chain handlers in a specified sequence such as...

```
First<FilterHandler>.Then<DoWorkHandler>().AndThen<SendConfirmationHandler>();
```

In terms of the content filtering, you can do this although you incur some transport overhead, meaning the queue will have to accept the message and the process will always call the first handler on every message(you can short-circuit the above pipeline at any point).  It may be the case that what you really want is a Distributor/Worker setup where all Workers are the same and you can handle some load.

If you truly have different endpoints with completely different logic, then I would have the Publisher process(only accepts and Publishes message) do the work of translating the inbound message to something else a Subscriber can then be interested in.  If then you find that a given Published message only ever has 1 Subscriber, then you don't need to Publish at all, you need to just Bus.Send() to the correct endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Adam. The workflow (transaction cycle) is however accept **1** message > various end points may operate on message > confirm all have finished before sending back a response. How would I know when all messages have finished being processed? I have no count to start with, and a timeout just isn't acceptable given an end point could be down and would still require the message to be processed before sending the response back to the third party.

Comment: In that case you definitely need a Saga to maintain the state across multiple endpoints.  It should be a simple one, started by the receipt of the message, and ending when all endpoints have confirmed completion.

Answer (score 0):

The way NServiceBus handles pub-sub is more like your option two.

1. A publisher service has an input queue and a subscription store.
2. A subscriber service has an input queue
3. The subscriber, on start-up will send a subscription message to the input queue of the publisher
4. The subscription message contains the type of message subscriber is interested in and the subscribers queue address
5. The publisher records the subscription in the subscription store.
6. The publisher receives a message.
7. The publisher evaluates the message type against the list of subscriptions
8. For each match found the publisher sends the message to the queue address.

In my opinion, you should stop thinking about destinations. Messages are messages. They should not have any inherent destination information in them. The subscription mechanism defines the addressing/routing requirements for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also thanks for explaining the inner working in a little more detail. In my mind I HAVE to think of destinations as explained in example 2. In example 2 while I'm not thinking of destinations in respect of end points since pub/sub is used, publishing a specific type of message which a particular end point requires is knowledge enough of the destination. This is frustrating as I want to make sure I use NServiceBus the way it is intended. Raising a message of type Destination1Message, or Destination2Message seems wrong.

Comment: [continued]
In my mind example 1 is the more generic example since the routing/message is destination unaware. It's the processing in the subscriber that does or doesn't do anything based on the content of the message.

Comment: I'm still looking for production like examples of pub/sub & message types. I can't seem to get away from having to publish messages which are request orientated rather than "something happened" orientated :'(